# Any shortcut for this code in php?

Tags: php

```
<?php
$s1="";$s2="qwe";$s3="zxc";

if(!empty($s1))
{
    $result=$s1;
}
else
{
    if(!empty($s2))
    {
        $result=$s2;
    }
    else
    {
        $result=$s3;
    }
}

echo "$result";
?>
```

Is there any possible code, probably of 1-2 lines, replacing the above mentioned code, I remember something like using "or" operator to do what I am doing with this code.

Comment: [The definitive guide to PHP's `isset` and `empty`](http://kunststube.net/isset)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$result = $s1 ? $s1 : ($s2 ? $s2 : $s3);
```

Or even shorter, if you have PHP >5.3:

```
$result = $s1 ?: ($s2 ?: $s3);
```

More: [PHP Manual part about Ternary Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

Comment: Just a note: My checks look like `$s1` instead of `!empty($s1)`, because the code seams to be always dealing with strings and the only check it performs is for determining if they contain anything. So in this case the code I have given is more than enough. However, if some other (more advanced) things will start to happen (eg. `$s1` or any other variable may be undefined), the first code I have given should be used, but with checks replaced using `empty()`. Before that make sure you understand [how `empty()` works](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).

Answer (score 1):

Try conditional the assignment operator:

```
$result = !empty($s1) ? $s1 : ( !empty($s2) ? $s2 : $s3 );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = $s1 ? $s1 : ($s2 ? $s2 : $s3);
```

why use this ?

since it reduce the complicity of the program

**Note:** The ternary operator is evaluated from left to right. So if you don't group the expressions properly, you will get an unexpected result

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
<?

$s1="";
$s2="qwe";
$s3="zxc";

echo $result = ($s1!="") ? $s1 : ( ($s2!="") ? $s2 : $s3);

?>
```

Output: 
qwe

It's ternary operator. If you have $s1 as not empty then it returns $s1 or else again checks the condition for $s2 if it also empty then it returns $s3.